# Reducing CPU usage of SDL_mutex in loop

Tags: c, multithreading, sdl

I wrote the following code to keep checking on `signal` (which is protected by an `SDL_mutex`) until its value is different from `0`. When that happens, it is saved into `s`.

```
char s = 0;
while(!s) {
    SDL_LockMutex(mutex);
    s = signal
    if(s) signal = 0;
    SDL_UnlockMutex(mutex);
}
```

But running this code will result in full CPU usage. It can be solved by adding an `SDL_Delay` inside the loop, but I need to check for the value constantly, so that can't work for me.

Any solutions?

Comment: Take a look at `SDL_CondWait`. The example code at https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_CondWait should help you.

Comment: Oh my god, that is literally what I'm trying to do, how could I miss that? Thank you very much!